# Salesforce 1 Apps complete custom branding

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, mobile

1. Is it possible to do a complete custom branding of salesforce 1 mobile app with no salesforce related logo/branding on it?
2. Is it possible to list it in any android or apple apps market?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, [to a limited extent.](http://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_sf1_branding.htm&language=en_US)
2. No. SF1 is closed-source; you cannot modify and recompile it. You can either build VF pages that are displayed in the standard SF1 app or you can build your own hybrid/native app and list it in an app store.

Comment: This may help in figure out what can be done: http://intmist.wordpress.com/2014/04/24/salesforce1-branding-customise-salesforce-look-and-feel-according-to-company-logo-and-color-theme/ . Good information provided with screens.